# Crystal Reports Formula : How to make value of a Numeric field to be empty if its value is zero?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have a numeric field(decimal in fact) in a report. And I need its value to stay in numeric format, because Sum of all rows be inserted after last row and if value of them change to string, then an error occurred(I think when calculating sum of them ran and sum for strings have not any meaning except concatenating).

Here is my last formula in DisplayString : (that causes error at runtime of course)

```
if {numericField} = 0 then "" else ToText({numericField})
```

What I want to learn is how can I tell to Crystal Reports replace zero values with null (or empty string or anything like this) and leave others?

**Note** that : I need sum of them in summarized section.

As [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403572/ryan) explained in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329542/crystal-reports-formula-how-to-make-value-of-a-numeric-field-to-be-empty-if-it#comment46854616_29329822), I should create a formula.
I do these:

[image: Steps I already did]

I'm new to Crystal report formulas. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a null numeric value by creating a formula with just a number in it, saving it, then deleting the number and re-saving. You'll be left with a formula that is empty but CR will treat it as a null value.

Then just use that formula instead of the empty string:
`if {numericField}=0 then {@NullNumeric} else {numericField}`

Comment: Thank @Ryan, but when I check this formula, this error shown : This field name is not known.   ( {@NullNumeric} I mean)

Comment: @AliBagheriShakib `{@NullNumeric}` is the formula that you have to create.

Comment: Ohm! My thought was it's a keyword or a constant. But it's exactly my problem! :) How to create that?

Comment: u r right! "creating a formula with just a number in it, saving it, then deleting the number and re-saving" you said. but i don't know how to do that cause i'm a bit new to crystal report formulas. can u write the expression i must use? thanks in advance bro...  :)

Comment: @AliBagheriShakib When you create your `{@NullNumeric}` formula all you have to do is enter a number (e.g. '1') and save it. Then, edit that same formula and delete the number so that your formula is completely empty and re-save it. That's it. CR will then treat that formula as a null numeric.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74051/discussion-between-ali-bagheri-shakib-and-ryan).